# Sharepoint 2010 - List Instance project

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint project that deploys list instances to sharepoint. This has been deployed as a wsp on production.
Now, I want to add some new lists and deploy again.

How should I go about this ? Can I retract and redeploy without losing the data? Is it feasible to do this or would I loose the lists if I retract?
Perhaps a better approach is to upgrade the feature to add the list instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used feature upgrading and I manage to modify existing list or add new ones